# How to get the seconds of day

Tags: go, time

How to get seconds of day (1 - 86400) in Go?

Just like http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getSecondOfDay()

Update/Clarifications

- Wanted equivalent of the joda/SecondOfDay in golang
- Expected to start at 0 and 86400 at end of the day
- Required when rewriting in golang a java opensource function which in turn is using joda/secondOfDay
- Googled '24 hour to seconds' to get 86400
- While asking question I could only think of now.Unix()-yesterdayMidnight.Unix() and the simple accepted answer didn't come to my mind
- Obviously didn't think about Daylight Saving
- Wanted to see if there is some built in function or popular/standard library

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: "seconds of day (1 - 86400)." During the transition to and from daylight saving time there are more or less than 86,400 seconds in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**
This function returns the nominal number of seconds of day in the (0 - 86399) range. If you're looking for the "number of seconds elapsed since midnight", which may not be in (0 - 86399) range due to daylight saving time, please see @icza's answer.

**Update:**
Please note also that the question refers to Joda Time implementation, which, according to [Joda Time getSecondOfDay on DST switch day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937961/joda-time-getsecondofday-on-dst-switch-day), seems to correspond to the nominal number of seconds implementation (as in my answer below) as opposed to the "number of seconds elapsed since midnight" (as in @icza's answer).

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func getSecondOfDay(t time.Time) int {
    return 60*60*t.Hour() + 60*t.Minute() + t.Second()
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(getSecondOfDay(t))
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of more complex way time.Now().Unix() - yesterdayMidNight.Unix()

Comment: This doesn't work on days when daylight saving happens. Also, `Time.Truncate()` operates on time as an absolute duration since the zero time, so it may also return incorrect result.

Comment: @icza: interesting point, can you share some examples when it fails?

Comment: Read the doc of [`Time.Truncate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate). Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/hAfBrYWNeZ

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, I removed that option from my answer

Comment: The one option you have still gives invalid results on days when daylight saving time happens.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition. @yodhevauhe asked for a function that returns (1 - 86400), so that seems to be just (60*60*h + 60*m + s) [technically, +1 also, but I'll skip that]. Your function is correct if we need "seconds since midnight", but that's not necessarily within the (1 - 86400) range, e.g. in your example with Central European time t := time.Date(2018, 10, 28, 23, 59, 59, 0, loc) would return 89999

Comment: @perl Exactly my point. If the clock is turned back, on that day there is more than 86400 seconds. So reporting more is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, if you define it as "seconds since midnight", while the question was "How to get seconds of day (1 - 86400) in Go?"

Comment: @icza: I have added a comment to my answer to clarify the point, and referred to your answer for the "seconds since midnight" version

Answer (score 4):

If we define "seconds of day" as the "elapsed seconds since midnight", then to get correct result even on days when [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) happens we should subtract the time representing midnight from the given time. For that, we may use [`Time.Sub()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Sub).

```
func daySeconds(t time.Time) int {
    year, month, day := t.Date()
    t2 := time.Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, t.Location())
    return int(t.Sub(t2).Seconds())
}
```

Testing it:

```
for _, t := range []time.Time{
    time.Date(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 30, 0, time.UTC),
    time.Date(2019, 1, 1, 0, 1, 30, 0, time.UTC),
    time.Date(2019, 1, 1, 0, 12, 30, 0, time.UTC),
    time.Date(2019, 1, 1, 12, 12, 30, 0, time.UTC),
} {
    fmt.Println(daySeconds(t))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wDCZBOOAqaX)):

```
30
90
750
43950
```

Let's see how this function gives correct result when daylight saving time happens. In Hungary, 25 March 2018 is a day when the clock was turned forward 1 hour at `02:00:00`, from `2 am` to `3 am`.

```
loc, err := time.LoadLocation("CET")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

t := time.Date(2018, 3, 25, 0, 0, 30, 0, loc)
fmt.Println(t)
fmt.Println(daySeconds(t))

t = t.Add(2 * time.Hour)
fmt.Println(t)
fmt.Println(daySeconds(t))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_3dlFTBw3su)):

```
2018-03-25 00:00:30 +0100 CET
30
2018-03-25 03:00:30 +0200 CEST
7230
```

We print the `daySeconds` of a time being 30 seconds after midnight, which is `30` of course. Then we add 2 hours to the time (2 hours = 2*3600 seconds = 7200), and the `daySeconds` of this new time will be properly `7200 + 30 = 7230`, even though the time changed 3 hours.